# Detect when user is starting/stopping typing in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typing

Once i was searching a solution for my issue and my issue was "I want to detect when user is typing and when he is stop typing so that i can update status."

I have created a sample. May it will work for you.

```
var typingTimer;
var doneTypingInterval = 10;
var finaldoneTypingInterval = 500;

var oldData = $("p.content").html();
$('#tyingBox').keydown(function() {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  if ($('#tyingBox').val) {
    typingTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      $("p.content").html('Typing...');
    }, doneTypingInterval);
  }
});

$('#tyingBox').keyup(function() {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  typingTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    $("p.content").html(oldData);
  }, finaldoneTypingInterval);
});



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<textarea id="tyingBox" tabindex="1" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
<p class="content">Text will be replace here and after Stop typing it will get back</p>
```

[View on Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/utbh575s/](http://jsfiddle.net/utbh575s/)

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is your question?

Comment: Your code is working.. What is the purpose of this question ?

Comment: Hi, yes it's working that why i have shared it. May it will be useful for others as well.

Comment: Then answer it Q&A style. Why put it in the question?

Answer (score 10):

Maybe what you want is the **debounce** functionality.

Basically it limits the rate at which a function can fire. So it waits a few *ms* before firing the event kind of like the user stopping the writing process.

Check this snippet

```js
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
 var timeout;
 return function() {
  var context = this, args = arguments;
  var later = function() {
   timeout = null;
   if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
  };
  var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
  if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
 };
};

// This will apply the debounce effect on the keyup event
// And it only fires 500ms or half a second after the user stopped typing
$('#testInput').on('keyup', debounce(function () {
  alert('typing occurred');
  $('.content').text($(this).val());
}, 500));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="testInput" />

<p class="content"></p>
```

Basically now it's up to you. Set your own time in *ms* and you're good to go.

Comment: Useful indeed. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed very useful.