# When start typing and timer countdown begin

Tags: python, timer, countdown

guys
I try to create some writing app, i have no idea how do i code in python for when i start typing in HTML textarea and start timer countdown, I'm using python flask and HTML, thank you so much.

```
@app.route("/begin", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def begin():
    global time_range
    time_range = int(request.form.get("time_input")) * 1
    print(time_range)
    start = "Begin..."

    return render_template("begin.html", start_btn=start_none, start=start, status=status_enable)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/joGsk.png

Comment: most likely you're going to need front-end -- JS -- code to do this, example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40019850/42346

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.